# What is a canonical Python way of traversing and processing two lists and creating new ones from them?

Tags: python

The following code works for me, but is not 'beautiful' / 'Pythonesque'. Can you suggest a more beautiful / pythonesque way of doing this?

```
    elite_states  = []
    elite_actions = []
    for session_i in range(0,len(states_batch)):
        for t in range(0,len(states_batch[session_i])):
            if (rewards_batch[session_i] >= reward_threshold):
                elite_states.append(states_batch[session_i][t])
                elite_actions.append(actions_batch[session_i][t])
```

I am new to Python and have read about list comprehension, and feel that there might be a better way of achieving what this code does. It takes three lists, E.g.:

```
    states_batch = [
        [1,2,3],   
        [4,2,0,2], 
        [3,1]      
    ]

    actions_batch = [
        [0,2,4],   
        [3,2,0,1], 
        [3,3]      
    ]
    rewards_batch = [
        3,         
        4,         
        5,         
    ]
```

Then creates two new lists which are filtered versions of 'states_batch' and 'actions_batch', depending on if the corresponding item in 'rewards_batch' matches a threshold.

I could imagine a Pythonesque way of doing this using list comprehension as something like:

elite_states = [ state for state in states_batch[x][y] if rewards_batch[x][y]>reward_threshold ]

But, of course, this includes to variables 'x' and 'y' that are 'implicit'

( By the way - this is part of a Corsera assigment on Reinforcement Learning. I am NOT asking for help to solve the assigment .. as the code above already works. I just want to improve my Python knowledge by writing more beautiful code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which illustrates your question.

Comment: What is `reward_threshold`? Please edit your question and put sample input and expected output.

Comment: reward_threshold is a decimal (real) number, as is the contents of all of the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. You loop over an enumeration of the list that contains the value you want to filter and if the value passes the threshold, you put the values at the given index into the "elite" lists.

```
elite_states, elite_actions = [], []
for i, val in enumerate(reward_batch):
    if val >= reward_threshold:
        elite_states.append(states_batch[i])
        elite_actions.append(actions_batch[i])
```

A core idea of Python is to always put readability above compactness (and even speed). Check out the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). If you respect these principles you can call your code "Pythonic".

Comment: Thank you Ulf. That certainly looks more elegant than my attempt. I will also pick up that reference.

Comment: You're welcome! And welcome to the Python community on SO :). Don't be too discouraged by the downvotes, it's probably because people consider your question too convoluted and specific. It's actually a simple thing you're trying to do, so another time try to give as minimal an example as possible that conceptually achieves what you want. Often that's also a good way to debug things yourself.

Comment: Ulf, Thank you for saying that - because those down-votes surely would put me off asking another question here. The question seems quite specific and succinct to me - but what do I know ..:-)